# Two row navigation, second row elements equal-width nav-justified

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

So trying to achieve responsive collapsible navigation with two rows, where first includes logo and language select and second row main links:

```
|                                                             |
|                             LOGO          lang              |
|        link1        link2         link3        link4        |
```

[jsfiddle snippet of progress so far](https://jsfiddle.net/virsis12/53rk7tgd/3/)

Cant get equal width for the main links, so that are distributed horizontally evenly on lg viewport and above.  With the structure and classes am using links are stacked very tight.

Second row navigation:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>    
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Categories
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item">Cat 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item">Cat 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item">Cat 3</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item">Cat 4</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Live Auction</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas how to override classes or other solution? Thanks!

Comment: So you want the links to be spread apart evenly?

Comment: @Adrift Yes, exactly. I have included link to jsfiddle, open full screen you will see second row links stacked very tight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the initial size of your flex items (`li`) to match content by changing the `flex-basis` from `0` to `auto` -- you can enable in Bootstrap 4 by using the [`flex-fill`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#fill) class. Add it to your HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item flex-fill">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Live Auction</a>
</li>
```

Or add the property in your CSS:

```
.nav-justified li.nav-item {
    /* ... */
    flex-basis: auto;
}
```

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/wcj1gzr5/1/

To distribute flex items with an effect like `justify-content: space-between` the width of the `div` and `ul` which contain the flex items should expand their width (giving available space to distribute flex items). To do this, set `min-width: 100%;` on both elements to have them fill their containing element and then use `justify-content` on the `ul` to control spacing & positioning.

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/wcj1gzr5/2/

Comment: I see this gets second row in one line, great! Except result am aiming is (or was...) spreaded evenly accross container, like https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#fill-and-justify Thats why have included nav-pills and nav-justified classes.

Comment: Truly spectacular! Will go outside to help someone too! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding `width:100%` to `.navbar-collapse, .nav-pills`. Below is the snippet for the same

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .navbar-collapse,
    .nav-pills {
      width: 100% !important
    }
    
    header {
      width: 100%;
      background: #282828;
      background-position-x: 0%;
      background-position-y: 0%;
      background-image: url("https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/65/40/cJtjUm.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }
    /* center the logo */
    
    .navbar {
      justify-content: center;
    }
    /* in order to center the logo */
    
    .navbar .navbar-toggler {
      position: absolute;
      right: 1rem;
      top: 0.5rem;
    }
    /* center all navbar items */
    
    .navbar-nav {
      align-items: center;
    }
    /* since it's expanding at lg */
    
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      /* in order to display in 2 rows */
      .navbar-expand-lg {
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
      }
      /* same logic as the navbar-toggler above */
      .navbar-nav.upper-controls {
        position: absolute;
        right: 1rem;
        top: 0.5rem;
        font-size: 85%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                            CompanyLogo
                        </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="navbar-nav upper-controls">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Language</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="navbar-nav nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        Categories
                                    </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Cat 1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Cat 2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Cat 3</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Cat 4</a>
                  </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Live Auction</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


</body>

</html>
```